# convert URL into file object using javascript only

Tags: javascript

Link given:

[example.com/data/videos/videoname.mp4](http://example.com/data/videos/videoname.mp4)

How to pass this link as fileInput?

```
var fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput);
```

All should be done in javascript only.
Need a solution in pure javascript only not using any jquery.

Comment: How deep is your knowledge of javascript?

Comment: i just want to know is it possible or not.

Comment: I have a link to grab the video from server side. but on client side i want to show it in blob using window.URL.createObjectURL(fileInput);

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax and get blob

```
var url = 'http://example.com/data/videos/videoname.mp4';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'blob:'+url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var myObject = this.response;
  }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: We are using couchDb as document database only. We do not want to store our video in blob format, we just want to convert our video http url to blob http url, just like youtube